# Bundle. Используемые типы

Tags: android

в Bundle можно передать только примитивные типы или Object тоже можно?

Answer (score 5):

Похоже, Bundle - это сериализатор, то есть в него можно передавать типы, которые могут быть сериализованы ([тут полный список](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) того, что он понимает), то есть всякие там списки и массивы, простые типы, `Serializable` и `Parcelable`. `Object` в лоб передать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

можете передать объект класс которого имплементирует интерфейс Serializable.
bundle.putSerializable(ваш класс);
при получении (тип вашего класса)bundle.getSerializable(ваш класс);